# changes in response for httpresponse

Tags: httpwebrequest, httpresponse

I am developing an online shop for a firm which have an online business management software called simPRO. so i have to retrieve from simPRO using an API which i am provided with. Its xml based and the commands have to be send using httpget or post.

i used this following code to get the data of products

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

```
    //byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uri);
    req.Method = "GET";

    using (WebResponse res = req.GetResponse())
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
        try
        {
            resultBox.Text = backstr;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            resultBox.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        sr.Close();
        res.Close();
    }
```

in the uri i have passed an xml script according to the API.

i am getting this response which is not what i expected.

meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content=0;url="index.php"

i am just confused that is there something wrong in the code above? or is it the xmlscript which i am passing?